# Using libxls with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, excel

I am planning to make an app whose data source is from an excel file.
So basically the desire outcome would be to make my app data in sync with the excel file.
I searched and found libxls and this seems to be a solution?

I downloaded the DHlibxls which is for xCode but have no success in running the provided test file.

Whenever I tried running I got the following error:

> Error validating server certificate for
>   'https://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net:443':
>   - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the fingerprint to validate the certificate manually! Certificate
>   information:
>    - Hostname: *.svn.sourceforge.net
>    - Valid: from Sat, 25 Feb 2012 23:58:41 GMT until Sun, 31 Mar 2013 19:51:44 GMT
>    - Issuer: GeoTrust, Inc., US
>    - Fingerprint: 0b:11:76:de:db:4c:74:72:cb:01:49:7d:13:70:c2:f1:13:7b:cb:bf (R)eject,
>   accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS of
>   'https://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/libxls/trunk/libxls':
>   Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted
>   (https://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net) Command /bin/sh failed with exit
>   code 1

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Answer (score 4):

for a more explicite answer click [here](http://rt.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68094-why-am-i-getting-a-certificate-validation-error-).

For this problem go to the command prompt, then type

```
svn list https://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net:443
```

then type

```
p
```

recompile your code and it should work

Answer (score 0):

This script seems to be running svn, maybe getting some files from SVN.  The error itself is saying that svn does not recognize the HTTPS certificate of the SourceForge SVN server.  You might get that if your time/date is set incorrectly, or it could be a number of other things.

Sourceforge recommends that you check that the HTTPS certificate is correct by checking the URL in your browser (https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Subversion):

> When you receive this error, we encourage you to validate that the
>   server is the correct server by putting your checkout URL into a
>   trusted web browser (i.e.
>   https://PROJECTNAME.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/PROJECTNAME).

You can do that in your case by copying this URL and pasting it into your browser:
https://libxls.svn.sourceforge.net:443/libxls/svnroot

Then in the browser URL field, there should be a little lock icon just the left of the URL, click on that. (I'm looking at Firefox).  Then click **More Information**, then click **View Certificate**.  Then you should see that the *SHA1 Fingerprint* is the same long hex string that you saw in the error:
0b:11:76:de:db:4c:74:72:cb:01:49:7d:13:70:c2:f1:13:7b:cb:bf

If it is the same, then you should type 'p' for store permanently.  If it is different, then there is something wrong with the connection or someone might be trying to "man in the middle" attack that site.